# how to not show list of options to open an intent if one is already open in android

Tags: android, android-intent, nfc

I am showing my application in list of options available to get NFC tag when its trigger.
I don't want to show the options if my application is already open.
Is it possible? and how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you want to receive NFC intents while your app is in the foreground, you should register your activity for the [foreground dispatch system](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/advanced-nfc.html#foreground-dispatch). That way, your activity gets precedence over other apps that registered for the same tag type in their app manifest. Thus, while your acitivity is in the foregorund, no activity chooser will be shown even if another app also has intent filters for these events.